# Galaxy S-4 Active connect via bluetooth to IMAC desktop

Tags: applications

Can I transfer data from my galaxy S-4 Active Phone to my Apple IMAC Desktop Via Bluetooth? Such as Music, Photos, files ??

Thanks 
Carl